# Scheme Double All List Values and Write Mapping Function

Tags: scheme, mapping

I have a question on a homework assignment that is as follows:

[image]

I have the first part (`double-list-elements`) complete

```
(define (double-list-elements s)
  (if (null? s)
  '()
  (cons (* 2 (car s))
        (double-list-elements (cdr s)))))
```

but I honestly have absolutely no idea how to proceed with `double-list-elements-one`.  Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Close But No Cigar:

```
(define (double-list-elements s)
  (if (null? s)
      '()
      (cons (* 2 (car s))
            (double-list-elements (cdr s)))))

(define (custom-map proc lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons (proc lst)
            (custom-map proc (cdr lst)))))

(define (double-list-elements-one func s)
  (custom-map double-list-elements s))

(double-list-elements-one double-list-elements '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
```

Output = `(list (list 2 4 6 8 10 12) (list 4 6 8 10 12) (list 6 8 10 12) (list 8 10 12) (list 10 12) (list 12))`

I need to pass double-list-elements to double-list-elements-one as a parameter as well as the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to write your own `map`, it's very *very* similar to what you already have, simply pass the part that changes as a procedure parameter, and invoke it on the right place:

```
(define (mymap proc lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      '()
      (cons <invoke proc on current element>
            (mymap proc (cdr lst)))))

(define (double-list-elements-one s)
  (mymap <pass a proper lambda> s))

(double-list-elements-one '(1 2 3 4 5))
=> '(2 4 6 8 10)
```

Comment: But the question says specifically I cannot use the built in map function and I have to make my own, which is where I am hung up.  I am extremely unfamiliar with this language.

Comment: @Gabriel_W ah! my bad. I updated my answer with a hint :)

Comment: I am close but getting some funky results. See above edits.

Comment: Two things about your newest edit: 1) you're applying the procedure to the _list_, not to its first element. 2) `double-list-elements` has nothing to do with it, what you must pass to `custom-map` is a `lambda` that doubles its parameter. Think about it, `map` is supposed to take a procedure that gets applied to a _single_ element, and `map` takes care of applying it to all the elements and building an output list for you - you don't have to worry about it!

Comment: @Gabriel_W You apply the whole list as argument so it's not `map`, but  `maplist` you have implemented.

Comment: @Gabriel_W also, take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Fmap..rkt%29._map%29%29) to better understand how `map` works, pay attention to the examples